# Lagrange eq is the geodesic equation if and only if the curve is parametrized by constant speed $∥\dot\gamma (t)∥$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. The length of an admissible
curve $\gamma : [a, b] \to M$ is defined by $L(γ) = \int_a^b ∥\dot \gamma (t)∥dt$.
1)Compute the Euler–Langrange equations for the variation of the length functional.
2)I want to show that these equations are the geodesic equation if and only if the curve is parametrized by constant speed $∥\dot\gamma (t)∥$

The E-L equation:

[image]

My attempt:

1. I just plugged $\scr  L=\|\dot \gamma (t)\|$ in the E-L equation and got this:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{g_{ij}\dot \gamma^i\dot \gamma^j}}2g_{ki}\dot \gamma^i\dot \gamma^j)-\partial_k g_{ij}\dot \gamma^i\dot \gamma^j=0\tag 1$
I didn't wanted to do the time derivative as the square root term makes it a pretty nasty equation
**Am I on the right track here?**

2. I think the Geodesic equation is (3.24) here:

[image]

I am not sure if this is indeed the equation that I should be obtaining, as as quoted in the picture (3.24 ) is the geodesic equation for the energy (3.23) and in my case I am working with the length, then the geodesic equation should be different, shouldn't it?

I am not sure how to do this part. Assuming 3.24 is indeed the geodesic equation that I want to obtain. There are two parts , since it is an iff:

i) If  $∥\dot\gamma (t)∥=const \implies (*)$ symplifies to $(3.24)$

ii) If $(*)$ is the geodesic equation, that is $(*)=(3.24)$, (not sure how to use this.. does it means one equation is the other times a constant?) then  $∥\dot\gamma (t)∥=$const.

**How do I complete this?**

Comment: I don't know the full answer to this.  But I think your first step is incorrect in the first term.  The first term should be $\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{g_{ij} \, \delta^i_k \, \dot\gamma^j + g_{ij} \, \dot\gamma^i \, \delta^j_k }{\sqrt{g_{ij} \dot\gamma^i \, \dot\gamma^j}}\right)$ or  $\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{g_{kj} \, \dot\gamma^j + g_{ik} \, \dot\gamma^i}{\sqrt{g_{ij} \dot\gamma^i \, \dot\gamma^j}}\right)$ or $\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{2 g_{ik} \, \, \dot\gamma^i}{\sqrt{g_{ij} \dot\gamma^i \, \dot\gamma^j}}\right)$.

Comment: Can you clarify the following: It is [known](https://www.akalin.com/curvature-moving-frames) that geodesic equations can be obtained from the Lagrangian
$$
\int_a^b\|\dot\gamma(t)\|^{\color{red}2}\,dt
$$
where $\|.\|$ is of course calculated with the metric $g\,.$ The parametrization of $\gamma$ should not matter. Is your question here how to do it with
$$
\int_a^b\|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt\,?
$$

Comment: @KurtG.  Yes, and in particular. Should working with one or the other lead to different equations?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer at the moment. As you have observed, the length functional $\int_a^b\|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt$ is much harder to use than the so called energy functional $\int_a^b\|\dot\gamma(t)\|^2\,dt\,.$ The former is treated on the sphere in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4532663/949989) where it produces meridians which, as we know, are ordinary geodesics.